# Writing the filter() function using for/while loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to understand how the `filter()` function works and would like to know 
how I could write:

```
test = filter(lambda x: x == y, lst)
```

using `for` or `while` loops.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted a couple of times, seems like a good question, albeit basic.  Beginner questions are welcome here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) is pretty much making a new list with a for loop and a conditional. In your example, it is identical to:

```
L = []
for i in lst:
    if i == y:
        L.append(i)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
[i for i in lst if i == y]
```

Comment: There was a time restriction on when I could accept it so I was just waiting.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Haidro’s answer, in Python 3 `filter` is a generator, so you could reimplement it like this:

```
def filter (test, lst):
    for x in lst:
        if test(x):
            yield x
```